# kitkat not displaying emoji

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, keyboard, twitter, emoticons

I have an LG G3 phone with kitkat (4.4.2), about 2 years old. When using the twitter app, there are some emoji I can't see (those belonging to Unicode 9). My LG keyboard only supports, AFAIK, Unicode 7 emoji. I have also tried installing Gboard but the emoji set is exactly the same one.

Although I have managed to survive so far without typing the newer emoji, I seriously can't forfeit seeing them on Twitter app (or any other place). Don't mind which version will be displayed (google, iOS, twitter or whatever) as long as they will be displayed (bonus points for a solution that will also include updating my emoji keyboard).

I am NOT interested in upgrading my OS, rooting or installing any other version - I'm completely fine with what I've got, just want to see those new food emoticons.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Emojis are releated to firmware/rom not to keyboard. So if you want to see new emojis you will have to updare android or flash custom rom. Maybe app called emoji switcher could help but it require root.

Answer (score 0):

Emoji are dependent to OS too! You cannot have a emoji(s) which was typed in upgraded versions of the OS. You need to update the OS.